# How can I hide form if first form is not validated properly

Tags: javascript, html

JavaScript:

```
function myFunction() { //creating the onlick function
    var locationFrom = document.getElementById("LocationFrom").value;// Getting both "from" and "to" Ids fromt he homepage.hmtl
    var locationTo = document.getElementById("LocationTo").value;

    if (locationFrom === locationTo) {  // If both have same values then give an error as below
        document.getElementById("errorLocationFrom").textContent = 'Destination cannot be the same.';
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("errorLocationFrom").textContent = ''; // if not the same then give no error
    }

$("#Submit").click(function(){
    $("#Form-2").show(); //Display form when Submit button is clicked 
});

function SecForm(){
    var ErrorLocation = document.getElementById("errorLocationFrom");

    if(ErrorLocation == false)       //Hide form2 if ErrorLocation is false 
       $("#Form-2").hide();

    return false;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="full-col">
<label for="FDestination">From</label> <!---Label for select element--->
<select name="Location" id = "LocationFrom">  <!---Select element to give user options to select from-->
    <option value="" disabled selected>Please Select </option> <!---Options for departing location-->
    <option value="Newport">Newport</option>
    <option value="Mahdi">London</option>
    <option value="Cardiff">Cardiff</option>
    <option value="Cilo">Brazil </option>
</select>

<label for="FDestination">To</label>
<select name="LocationTo" id = "LocationTo" >
    <option value="" disabled selected>Please Select </option>
    <option value="Cardiff">Cardiff</option>
    <option value="Mahdi">London</option>
    <option value="Newport">Newport</option>
    <option value="Cilo">Brazil</option>
</select>
<!---Hidden Error message only shown when there is a validation error for departing and arrival--->    
<label id="errorLocationFrom"></label> 
</form>

<Form action="#" class="group" name="form2" id="Form-2" method="post" hidden = "true">
    <legend id="fixed"><span class="number">2</span>Tickets</legend> 
    <div class="half-col">
        <label for="Adult-ticket" class="center-label">Adults(+16)</label>
        <input type="number" id="adult" name="user_adult">
        <label id="AdTickError"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="half-col">
        <label for="child-ticket" class="center-label">Child</label>
        <input type="number" id="child" name="user_child">
        <label id="ChildTickError"></label>
    </div>

    <input type="checkbox" id="Standard" name="Type" value="Standard">
    <label class="light" for="Standard">Standard</label><br>

    <input type="checkbox" id="First-Class" name="Type" value="First-Class">
    <label class="light" for="First-Class">First Class</label><br><br>
    <p id="total-cost"></p>
    <button type = "button" value="checkout" id="checkoutbtn" onclick="AdultNumber(); calculateFare(); " >CHECKOUT</button>
</Form>
```

I am making a railway ticketing system and what I need, is the form to do is first be validated then after clicking the Submit button it will display the other form both forms are on the same page.

Comment: As it stands, I think "if(ErrorLocation == false)" will always evaluate to false. The dom object is created in your markup, therefore it exists, so you're comparing an object against a false boolean (coalescing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change the submit of form1 to input type button. When button1 is clicked you do your validation as before and if it is passed you show the form2.

In form2 you could use the *onsubmit* event to copy the fields you need from form1 to form2; `<form id="Form-2" onsubmit="CopyData()">`

In copy function you can do:

```
$('#Form-2').append( '<input type="hidden" name="LocationFrom" value="' + $('#LocationFrom').val() + '">' );
$('#Form-2').append( '<input type="hidden" name="LocationTo" value="' + $('#LocationTo').val() + '">' );
```

UPDATE - fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/blocknotes/copyuwyd/